# getAllEntries() of NotesView in Domino To Go for Titanium returns null

Tags: titanium, dominotogo

If you have for example this code:

```
var db = new NotesDatabase("https://address.com/mobile.nsf", "Database"); 
var view = db.getView("PolicyData"); 
var vec = view.getAllEntries(); 
if(!vec) { 
alert("nothing in view"); 
return; 
} 

var ve = vec.getFirstEntry();
```

it will fail because vec is null. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you need to synchronize the view with the Domino backend first, so that it's data is in the the local SQLite database of the device.

This would work:

```
var db = new NotesDatabase("https://address.com/mobile.nsf", "Database"); 
var view = db.getView("PolicyData"); 
var callback = function() {
var vec = view.getAllEntries(); 
if(!vec) { 
alert("nothing in view"); 
return; 
} 

var ve = vec.getFirstEntry(); 
}

view.update(callback);
```

See http://www.youatnotes.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-dtg.nsf/dx/NotesView#Methods for more details about the update method.